# How to group all records for an employee to one line in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-grouping

I am working on an XSLT code to generate a fixed length file output that will have multiple payment amounts for the same employee. Currently, the XSLT file is generated in a way where multiple lines will be available for the same employee if there're more than one payments for them in the same run.

Looking for an option to get the record into one line per employee. Please advise.

[![Sample record][1]][1]

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Export/Record">
<xsl:sort select="Last_Name"/>
<xsl:if test="Employment_Indicator='Regular' or Employment_Indicator='Executive' or Employment_Indicator='Internship'">
    <xsl:if test="EmploymentStatusID  = 'ACTIVE'">
        <xsl:if test="DeductionName = 'HSA - Self' or DeductionName = 'HSA - Family' 
 or DeductionName = 'Dependent Care - Single' or DeductionName = 'Dependent Care - Family'
 or DeductionName = 'Health Flex' or DeductionName = 'Health Flex Limited Purpose' ">
            <xsl:if test="prd_effstart !=''">
                <xsl:if test="pp_suffix = '00'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Record_Type"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="Employee_Person_ID = ''">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$zeros"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Employee_Person_ID"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="translate(Last_Name, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/> -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(Last_Name, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 
                                      substring($spaces, 1, 30 - string-length(Last_Name)))"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(First_Name, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 
                                      substring($spaces, 1, 20 - string-length(First_Name)))"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="DeductionName = 'Health Flex'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(FSA * 100, '000000000000000')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="DeductionName = 'Health Flex Limited Purpose'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(FSALP * 100, '000000000000000')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:text/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <!--Employee DCSA Contribution -->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="DeductionName = 'Dependent Care - Single'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(DCS * 100, '000000000000000')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="DeductionName = 'Dependent Care - Family'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(DCFM * 100, '000000000000000')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:text/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

</xsl:for-each>

Comment: I have added the "xsl-grouping" tag. Click on that and you will find many similar questions. Note that grouping is much easier in XSLT 2.0/3.0 than in 1.0, so it's especially important to state any constraints you have on the XSLT version used.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including an example XML input, an **executable** XSLT, and the expected output, and state which version of XSLT your processor supports.